# How to find Root element values?

Tags: java, xml, parent-child, xmlnode

I am creating an Excel sheet from an XML where I need to produce a result like:

```
Current node name | Parent name
```

I have previously worked with traversing through an XML file and retrieving entries from it.. But I don't know how to find the parent of a particular node.

Does anybody have any knowledge how to find the parent node of a current node?

**Sample XML:**

```
<node>
  <id> 1 </id>
  <name> One </name>
  <node>
    <id> 2 </id>
    <name> Two </name>
  </node>
  <node> 
    <id> 3 </id>
    <name> Three </name>
  </node>
 .....
```

Here, nodes with id 2 and 3 have node with id = 1 as their parent.. So I want my Excel to look like:

```
Child | Parent
2     | 1 
3     | 1
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [getParentNode](http://www.w3.org/2003/01/dom2-javadoc/org/w3c/dom/Node.html#getParentNode__) method:

```
node.getParentNode();
```